# Why is $\log n+\log \frac{n}{2}+\log \frac{n}{4}+\log \frac{n}{8}+\cdots+\log \frac{n}{n}=\Theta (\log^2 n)$?

Tags: runtime-analysis, performance

$$\log n+\log \frac{n}{2}+\log\frac{n}{4}+\log\frac{n}{8}+\cdots+\log\frac{n}{n}=\Theta (\log^2n).$$

The sum of logarithms is the logarithm of the product $n\cdot\frac{n}{2}\cdot\frac{n}{4}\cdot\frac{n}{8}\cdots\frac{n}{n}$. This equals $n^{\log n}$ divided by what? If the product would just be $n^{\log n}$, then this would make perfect sende since $ \log(n^{\log n})=\log(n)\cdot\log(n)=\log^2 n$. But the divisor equals $\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{8}\cdot\frac{1}{16}\cdots\frac{1}{n}$ so I don't get it.

Comment: Try to write the summation in the form $\sum_{i=0}^{\log n} a_i$ for a suitable $a_i$ (which also depends on $n$). Then you will likely find a better way to deal with the logarithm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming $n$ is a power of $2$, you have:
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{\log n} \log \frac{n}{2^i} =
\sum_{i=0}^{\log n} \left( \log n - i \right) =
\sum_{i=0}^{\log n} i =
\frac{(\log n)(\log n+1)}{2} = \Theta(\log^2 n).
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! Why is $\sum_{i=0}^{\log n} \left( \log n - i \right) =
\sum_{i=0}^{\log n}i$?

Comment: The addends of the first sums are the integers from $\log n$ to $0$, in descending order. The addends of the second sum are the same integers but in ascending order.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $n=2^k$, and we define $T(n)= \sum_{i=1}^{\log n}\log \left(\frac{n}{2^i}\right)$:

First we must find out number of  logarithm terms in form $\log \frac{n}{2^k}$,
that told us, because of $k=\log n$ then number of logarithm terms is $\log n$.

So we can act as follow
$$ \sum_{i=1}^{\log n}\log \left(\frac{n}{2^i}\right)\leq\sum_{i=1}^{\log n}\log \left(n\right)=\mathcal{O}(\log^2n)$$
So the upper bound is $$T(n)=\mathcal{O}(\log^2n).$$

On the other hand to finding lower bound we act as follow:

$$\log\left(\frac{n^{\log n}}{2^{2\log n}}\right) \leq\sum_{i=1}^{\log n}\log \left(\frac{n}{2^i}\right) $$

$$=\hspace{4pt}\log\left(\frac{n^{\log n}}{n^2}\right)\leq \sum_{i=1}^{\log n}\log \left(\frac{n}{2^i}\right)$$

$$=\hspace{4pt}\log\left(n^{\log n-2}\right)\leq \sum_{i=1}^{\log n}\log \left(\frac{n}{2^i}\right)$$
$$=\hspace{4pt}(\log n-2)\log n\leq \sum_{i=1}^{\log n}\log \left(\frac{n}{2^i}\right)$$

So according to the left side of inequality  our lower bound is
$$T(n)=\Omega(\log^2 n)$$
Finally
$$ T(n)=\theta(\log^2 n).$$